# Get jQuery version from inspecting the jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to find out what version of jQuery is being used by inspecting the `jQuery` object? jQuery is dynamically getting added to my page and I cannot see any reference to it in my markup. If I inspect it in my browser's console, it's there.

Answer (score 558, accepted):

You can use either [`$().jquery;`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) or [`$.fn.jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) which will return a string containing the version number, e.g. `1.6.2`.

Comment: Note that the version is not always precise to three levels. jQuery 1.4.0 for example prints just `1.4` for `jQuery.fn.jquery`

Comment: fyi, as of 2.1.4, you can use just `$.fn.jquery`, no need to *call* the `$` function now

Comment: It doesn't work when you load jquery "globaly" via webpack's 3 "ProvidePlugin" feature.

Comment: @StLia You may need to import the jQuery object... `import jQuery from jquery`

Answer (score 41):

FYI, for the cases where your page is loading with other javascript libraries like mootools that are conflicting with the `$` symbol, you can use `jQuery` instead.

For instance, `jQuery.fn.jquery` or `jQuery().jquery` would work just fine:

[image: screen shot for checking jQuery version]

Answer (score 14):

`$().jquery` will give you its version as a string.

Comment: $ is a reference to the jQuery function and $() references a jQuery instance (just in case anyone wonders why)

Comment: Easy to copy/paste... :)

Answer (score 13):

For older versions of jQuery

```
jQuery().jquery  (or)

jQuery().fn.jquery
```

For newer versions of jQuery

```
$().jquery  (or)

$().fn.jquery
```

Comment: The first syntax `jQuery().jquery` worked for me with a very old version of jQuery (embedded on a legacy project): `1.10.2`

Answer (score 12):

```
$()['jquery']
```

Invoke `console.log($())` and take note about jquery  object fields :

- jquery
- selector
- prevObject

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can get the version of the jquery by simply printing `object.jquery`, the `object` can be any object created by you using `$`.

For example: if you have created a `<div>` element as following

```
var divObj = $("div");
```

then by printing `divObj.jquery` will show you the version like 1.7.1

Basically `divObj` inherits all the property of `$()` or `jQuery()` i.e if you try to print `jQuery.fn.jquery` will also print the same version like 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log( 'You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery );
```