# How to check what version of jQuery is loaded?

Tags: jquery

How do I check which version of jQuery is loaded on the client machine? The client may have jQuery loaded but I don't know how to check it. If they have it loaded how do I check the version and the prefix such as:

```
$('.class')
JQuery('.class')
```

Comment: The client may have jQuery loaded if you included it as a file to download. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Dunno about what the OP needs it for, but if you're making a script or plugin that requires jQuery you could check and throw an error if it's not there or a too old version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get jQuery version from inspecting the jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867040/get-jquery-version-from-inspecting-the-jquery-object)

Answer (score 1037, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

Comment: There are 2 ways to check currently loaded jquery version: `jQuery.fn.jquery` and `jQuery().jquery` (shorthands: `$.fn.jquery` `$().jquery`). I wrote about [**it in details**](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-check-jquery-version.html) with links to jquery source code if you'd like to dig deeper.

Comment: even simpler version 
`if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}`

Comment: The check for undefined should be `!==`

Comment: Note lowercase :)

Comment: Don't use `jQuery().jquery`. It creates a jQuery object for nothing, just use what the answer says.

Comment: This answer will do the job and is a good answer. However, `$.fn.jquery` or `jQuery.fn.jquery` will get the same result just in the console and not as an alert; no need to overcomplicate it. Also I'd go with the comparison as `if (typeof jQuery !== undefined) { ... }`

Comment: *It creates a jQuery object for nothing* - oh noes!  That extra 0.001ms just before displaying an *alert* - how will we cope?

Answer (score 43):

My *goto* means to determine the version:

```
$.fn.jquery
```

Another similar option:

```
$().jQuery
```

If there is concern that there may be multiple implementations of `$` — making `$.` ambiguous — then use `jQuery` instead:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

Recently I have had issues using `$.fn.jquery` and `$().jQuery` on a few sites so I wanted to note a third simple command to pull the jQuery version.

> If you get back a version number — usually as a string — then jQuery is loaded and that is what version you're working with. If not loaded then you should get back `undefined` or maybe even an error.

Pretty old question and I've seen a few people that have already mentioned my answer in comments. However, I find that sometimes great answers that are left as comments can go unnoticed; especially when there are a lot of comments to an answer you may find yourself digging through piles of them looking for a gem. Hopefully this helps someone out!

Comment: @Janar No, it's not at all exactly the same. Overly complicated in contrast, IMO.

Comment: Have you tried type "5" in your console? Then the next "$_" will give you "5".

Answer (score 37):

You can just check if the `jQuery` object exists:

```
if( typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ) ... // jQuery loaded
```

`jQuery().jquery` has the version number.

As for the prefix, `jQuery` should always work. If you want to use `$` you can wrap your code to a function and pass `jQuery` to it as the parameter:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $( '.class' ).doSomething();  // works always
})( jQuery )
```

Comment: The `if( jQuery )` will throw an exception if `jQuery` is unknown and it won't work.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in `try {...}catch(e){...}`?

Comment: Don't use `jQuery().jquery`. It creates a jQuery object for nothing. _(copied comment from another answer)_

Answer (score 19):

…just because this method hasn't been mentioned so far - open the console and type:

```
$ === jQuery
```

As @Juhana mentioned above `$().jquery` will return the version number.

Comment: something like `($ === jQuery)?$().jquery:'no jquery';`

Comment: OP asked to check the version loaded. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 18):

I have found this to be the shortest and simplest way to check if jQuery is loaded:

```
if (window.jQuery) {
    // jQuery is available.

    // Print the jQuery version, e.g. "1.0.0":
    console.log(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

This method is used by http://html5boilerplate.com and others.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo I edited the answer to include how to get the version number, after making sure jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 7):

My preference is:

```
console.debug("jQuery "+ (jQuery ? $().jquery : "NOT") +" loaded")
```

Result:

jQuery 1.8.0 loaded

Comment: I get : undefined

Comment: This is a bit better, but logging isn't that useful when working on an app. You're better off saving a variable first.
```let has$ = typeof jQuery === 'function'; console.log('jQuery' + (has$ ? ` version ${jQuery.fn.jquery} loaded.` : ' is not loaded.'));
```

Answer (score 4):

In one line and the minimum of keystrokes (oops!):

```
alert($().jquery);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should actually wrap this in a try/catch block for IE:

```
// Ensure jquery is loaded -- syntaxed for IE compatibility
try
{
    var jqueryIsLoaded=jQuery;
    jQueryIsLoaded=true;
}
catch(err)
{
    var jQueryIsLoaded=false;
}
if(jQueryIsLoaded)
{
    $(function(){
        /** site level jquery code here **/
    });
}
else
{
    // Jquery not loaded
}
```

Comment: IE doesn't handle `typeof jQuery != 'undefined'`? Is this true for every IE or just the older ones?

Comment: Pretty sure it's for the legacy versions. Still what's more embarrassing than a big ol' JS error preventing your page from working, regardless if it's the browser's fault ;)

Comment: This has really helped me a lot. I was struggling to get the exact behavior across Firefox and IE for checking whether jQuery is loaded or not using WatiN. Now with this workaround, I am very happy. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

With [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) this can be done with `window.jQuery?.fn?.jquery`. This one liner also works if jQuery isn't loaded at all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the developer's Tool > console and write one of the following command
 `jQuery.fn.jquery`
`console.log(jQuery().jquery);`

Answer (score 1):

As per [Template monster blog](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-check-jquery-version-using-firebug-console.html), typing, these below scripts will give you the version of the jquery in the site you are traversing now.

```
 1. console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
 2. console.log(jQuery().jquery);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe self explanatory, but simplest method I have found is looking at the version commented in the actual file (typically jquery.min.js).  Alternatively,if something like code.jquery.com is used, version number is in https reference (ie https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGFHG.png)

Answer (score -3):

```
if (jQuery){
   //jquery loaded
}
```

.....

Comment: Some other libraries use `$`.

Comment: What if they're using Prototype? Or anything else that uses `$`? It's not unique to jQuery.

Comment: What if `jQuery` isn't loaded? (It'll throw a `ReferenceError`). The above answer is correct, and that's why people are down-voting your answer.