# The best way to know if JQuery is available?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if jQuery is loaded and what version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-if-jquery-is-loaded-and-what-version)

What is the best way to check to see if JQuery is loaded?

Comment: What are you currently using? What issues are you facing with it?

Comment: @clamp: This *will* bite you - Prototype also uses `$`. `if (jQuery)` perhaps?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  // jQuery is NOT available
} else {
  // jQuery is available
}
```

Comment: This is completely backwards. -1

Comment: ops.. I've corrected, thanks for pointing that out :-)

Answer (score 0):

look on http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html

***Method 1:***

```
if (jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded
}
```

***Method 2:***

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded  
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
}
```

***in try catch***

```
try
{
     var jqueryIsLoaded = jQuery;
     jQueryIsLoaded = true;
}
catch(err)
{
     var jQueryIsLoaded = false;
}

if(jQueryIsLoaded) 
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: Method1: reference error if not

Comment: Can you combine this with a `try/catch`?

Comment: @XyanEwing: you could, but it would be pretty bad/slow'ish. Much better is the usage of the `in operator`. `if( 'jQuery' in window ) {}`

Comment: The try catch method combined with `typeof jQuery === 'undefined'` solved my issue