# IE8 and bootstrap compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

You can see my app at kogarah.herokuapp.com

I'm having a problem getting this to look ok in IE8 and I need to make it work with this version of the browser. I suspect it's something to do with container width.

The li in the navbar are all showing underneath each other rather than in a straight horizontal line, and there are similar issues with the main parts of the pages too, where I use bootstrap's grid system.

I have read the bootstrap documentation about IE8 compatibility but have still not been able to solve this.

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you running. 1.x or 2.x ? 2.x removes support for IE 8 and below

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but not sure how to check this. My gemfile just has gem 'jquery-rails'...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded OR check at the top of the `jquery.js` file.

Comment: `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->`

Technically, you don't need to traverse up the tree to get those files when you app is pushed to heroku. I doubt that is the problem, but I would switch it to `src="/assets/js/respond.min.js"` instead and see if that clears it.