# What version of GWT is a site using?

Tags: gwt, version

Suppose that I am on a site that is using GWT and I want to find out what version of GWT it is using.  How can I do this?

---

If the site was using dojo, I would use the following in the console:

```
dojo.version
```

[Source](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/version.html).

---

JQuery also has similar functionality:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973954/251589).

---

How can I do this in GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK: there is no simple way of getting the `GWT` version from a deployed GWT app.

However you can have a look at the Chrome Extension "[Library Detector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/library-detector/cgaocdmhkmfnkdkbnckgmpopcbpaaejo)" which supports `GWT` (also the version). I tested it and at least for normal deployed GWT apps it works.

The code for how it does it can be found [here](https://github.com/andrewbredow/Library-Detector-for-Chrome/blob/master/library/libraries.js#L3).

Comment: Awesome!  This is not exactly what I was looking for but is very useful.