# How can I know the version of jQuery using the no conflict mode?

Tags: jquery

I have on my page 2 version of jQuery, in one of them I add the

```
var costumName = $.noConflict(true);
```

Is there a way to print the version uses the no conflict ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check what version of jQuery is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the jQuery version:

```
$.fn.jquery
```

So to get the second one, defined as `costumName`, it should be:

```
costumName.fn.jquery
```