# How to check if local JavaScript packages are Semver?

Tags: javascript, npm, semantic-versioning

In my project, the previous developers have put various of JS packages locally, such as `chart.js`, `jquery.block-ui.js`, `modernizr.js`, `axios.js`, `vue.js`, etc. I'm trying to manage them using NPM. Problem is, they are all old versions.

Q1: how do I know if they are `Semver` so it's safe to upgrade them to the latest minor version? I did my research for each package but it's troublesome to look into each one and some of them have very little information about it. Is there somewhere stating all `Semvered` JS packages?

Q2: for `jquery.block-ui.js`, it is minified, in the file, there is no information about the version number, in this case, is it possible to find out what version it is thus if it's safe to upgrade?

Comment: you never know. that's why you have to write tests. in addition to that, even if a package is semver.. i experienced alot of packages where breaking changes were introduced in patch version changes.

Comment: To but what GottZ said more bluntly: *it is **never** "safe" to upgrade a package*. Ever. It is frequently *necessary*, but it is never *safe*. You'll have to just do it one at a time and see what breaks. Start by replacing one of the local files with the latest version from npm in node_modules. Run tests, check visuals. Repeat. Sucks, but the only way to eat technical debt is to start chewing and keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note: I'm keeping this answer up for future people who had sensible predecessors and are looking for help. I will edit again if I think of something that will help someone who's previous dev copied in their files by hand)

- Firstly, use `npm outdated`. This will check for any outdated packages. Nothing to be gained from curing the healthy.
- Second, as the comment says about semvered packages, you never know. That said, I have found a semi-useful resource [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ly7O1x/3/), its a regex that returns semvered version numbers as matches.
- Third, about the JQuery, `npm outdated` should return a table stating version numbers. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded) question about other possible ways to find a JQuery version number.

Here is the example output they gave for `npm outdated`:

```
Package      Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
glob          5.0.15   5.0.15    6.0.1  test-outdated-output
nothingness    0.0.3      git      git  test-outdated-output
npm            3.5.1    3.5.2    3.5.1  test-outdated-output
local-dev      0.0.3   linked   linked  test-outdated-output
once           1.3.2    1.3.3    1.3.3  test-outdated-output
```

I hope this helps. It may not. Like the comments say, you can never be sure so the surest way is to go through them one at a time and see what breaks

Comment: @JaredSmith is right, previous devs put files in the project, so package manager has never been used before my investigation.

Comment: Im sorry to OP for misinterpreting the true horror the previous dev left behind... Im doing my best to think of a solution