# How to know jQuery version programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get jQuery version from inspecting the jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867040/get-jquery-version-from-inspecting-the-jquery-object)

Pretty much that..

I don't know which jQuery version gets loaded every time, so I want to be able to react differently for different versions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

jQuery exposes its version on the `prototype` (`.fn`):

```
console.log( jQuery.fn.jquery );
```

outputs the string `"1.8.0"` for instance.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Returns string Ex: "1.3.1"
$().jquery;

// Also returns string Ex: "1.3.1"
jQuery.fn.jquery;
```