# Jquery version check

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check the jquery version check.  Tried the following commands in the console:

1. jQuery. fn. jquery
2. jQuery(). jquery

but both are printing as "jquery" instead of version number. Please help me on this. 
The question might be a duplicate but none of them worked for me. so posting again.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.jquery` works fine for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check what version of jQuery is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973941/how-to-check-what-version-of-jquery-is-loaded)

Comment: None of them worked for you, so you must be doing something different, eg not including jquery correctly.  You'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates *your* problem, as the question, as it stands, has a very straightforward answer, so we need to know what's different about your scenario.

Comment: `javascript:(()=>alert(window.jQuery&&jQuery.fn.jquery))()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use either $().jquery; or $.fn.jquery which will return a string containing the version number, e.g. 1.6.2

or

Invoke console.log($()) and take note about jquery object fields

or

console.log('You are running jQuery version: ' + $.fn.jquery)

Comment: I have tried these things as well but everywhere it's returning only "jquery" instead of version number

Comment: may be your jquery is not loaded please check your jquery is loaded or not `if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);`
}

Comment: Even the above one resulted in an alert box with the string "jquery"

Comment: If resolved mark it correct, it is useful for other people as well

Comment: I have tried all of the above ones and none of them gave me the version. What is the test code you need?

Answer (score 2):

`$().jquery` will give you its version as a string.

Link [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6867094)

[sourse 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736479)

For older versions of jQuery

```
jQuery().jquery  
jQuery().fn.jquery
```

For newer versions of jQuery

```
$().jquery
$().fn.jquery
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code in console of chrome dev tools

> $.fn.jquery

This provides version of jQuery as a string

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is loaded => print the version
    alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
}
```

It's work for me, try it